# License that prevents SaaS hosting

Tags: licensing

I want to develop a web app for which I want to make the source code available, but I want to prevent others from offering my web app as a hosted service.

Is there any existing license (which would obviously not comply to Open Source) that covers this scenario?

Comment: Why are you asking for a license "which would obviously not comply to Open Source" on Open Source SE? Also why did you not consider Affero GPL? It does not "prevent" SaaS as such, but it says that the provider must give the source code to the users of the service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no Free or Open source license will permit such restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

There are license which go in that direction, but not sure there exists one which completely forbids offering SaaS of a software.

MongoDB recently switched to their license to [SSPL](https://www.mongodb.com/licensing/server-side-public-license) which requires anyone to make available everything needed to run the instance of their database including all tools so that anyone can build that service as-offered.

A similar thing happend recently for [Redis Lab](https://redislabs.com/legal/licenses/) which might even come closer to what you seek. On [ArsTechnica](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2019/10/is-the-software-world-taking-too-much-from-the-open-source-community/) there's a read-worthy article with some background on these things.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the "Commons Clause", which should solve my problem.

Is it enough to add the following LICENSE.txt file to my project or did I make any mistake or overlook something?

```
                                    <PRODUCT> Licensing
                    Copyright 2019-2020 Daniel Berghold (public@<my domain>.cc)

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License") modified with Commons Clause
Restriction; you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a
copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions
and limitations under the License.

Commons Clause Restriction

The Software is provided to you by the Licensor under the License, as defined below, subject to
the following condition.

Without limiting other conditions in the License, the grant of rights under the License will not
include, and the License does not grant to you, the right to Sell the Software.

For purposes of the foregoing, “Sell” means practicing any or all of the rights granted to you
under the License to provide to third parties, for a fee or other consideration (including without
limitation fees for hosting or consulting/ support services related to the Software), a product or
service whose value derives, entirely or substantially, from the functionality of the Software.
Any license notice or attribution required by the License must also include this Commons Clause
License Condition notice.

For purposes of the clause above, the “Licensor” is Daniel Berghold (public@<my domain>.cc) the 
“License” is the Apache License, Version 2.0, and the Software is the <PRODUCT> software provided
with this notice.
```

Comment: This is a non-free/open source license and is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score -1):

I believe AGPL satisfies your needs. Note that forbidding certain uses makes the license not open source.

Comment: AGPL doesn't prevent hosting software, it just requires you to provide the code to users who interact with it over a network.